# Comparing Master List to Individual lists in a CSV row

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I am trying to automate my classroom, and I'm hitting a wall with comparing my total list of students to a dataframe that has classes and students. Ultimately, the code would return a list of full classes.

First, my total students list is called `all_kids`.

```
all_kids=['Kevin', 'Jack', 'Caroline', 'Grace', 'Harry', 'Sam']
df_kids=pd.DataFrame(all_kids)
```

Then, my class info is in a CSV file, where one column is the class period and one column is the students in that class

| Name | Kids |
| --- | --- |
| English | Kevin, Jack, Sam, Richard |
| Math | Caroline, Kevin, Harry, Grace |

Is there a way to compare my total list of kids to the kids in each class and return something like this:

| Name | Kids | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| English | Kevin, Jack, Sam, Richard | Not Full |
| Math | Caroline, Kevin, Harry, Grace | Full. |

Here, Math is full because those four kids all appear in `all_kids`, but English is not full because Richard is not included in `all_kids`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` to split the strings in the `Kids` column then use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) + [`.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to create a boolean mask which is then used with `np.where` to select the corresponding `Status`:

```
m = df_class['Kids'].str.split(r', ', expand=True).isin(all_kids).all(1)
df_class['Status'] = np.where(m, 'Full', 'Not Full')
```

Alternatively you can `split` the strings in the `Kids` column, then inside a list comprehension check for `set` membership using [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20issubset#frozenset.issubset):

```
m = [set(k.split(', ')).issubset(all_kids) for k in df_class['Kids']]
df_class['Status'] = np.where(m, 'Full', 'Not Full')
```

---

```
      Name                           Kids    Status
0  English      Kevin, Jack, Sam, Richard  Not Full
1     Math  Caroline, Kevin, Harry, Grace      Full
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is checking if every name present in the 'Kids' variable is present in all_kids. In logics, it means to exclude `all_kids` from each line of `Kids` and watch if it is empty or not.
Of course, you first need to split you `Kids` str column to a column of lists :

This code worked for me :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

all_kids=['Kevin', 'Jack', 'Caroline', 'Grace', 'Harry', 'Sam']
df_kids=pd.DataFrame(all_kids)


df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns =  ['Name', 'Kids'])
df.loc[0] = ['English', 'Kevin, Jack, Sam, Richard']
df.loc[1] = ['Math', 'Caroline, Kevin, Harry, Grace']

df['list'] = df['Kids'].apply(lambda s : s.split(', '))
df['diff'] = df['list'].apply(lambda s : [elt for elt in s if elt not in all_kids]).apply(len)
df['Status'] = np.where(df['diff'] == 0, 'Full', 'Not Full')
```

```
      Name                           Kids  ... diff    Status
0  English      Kevin, Jack, Sam, Richard  ...    1  Not Full
1     Math  Caroline, Kevin, Harry, Grace  ...    0      Full
```